# simplexml_load_string inconsistent results

Tags: php, simplexml

This is strange and I'm struggling to figure out how to solve it.

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><myinfo><myname>Foo</myname></myinfo>';
$return_data_obj = simplexml_load_string($xml);
echo "ARRAY: <pre>" . print_r((array)$return_data_obj, 1) . "</pre>";
```

Results are inconsistent ... Hit F5 for refresh, I see the array, Hit F5 again, good ... results. Hit F5 empty array, again F5, empty again, then F5 array show sup and so on. No code in change, just simple refresh. I've tried everything i could find, adding extra parms in simplexml_load_string, namespace, etc - nothing helped.

Anyone have any idea?

NOTE: I'm on PHP 5.3.2

Comment: why are you printing the wrong object (`$xmlObject`) when you are loading the object in `$return_data_obj`

Comment: You were right - this was simply me trying other things and forgot to edit my code. Same output if i print (array)$return_data_obj.

Comment: you can accept the answer if you find that helpful

Comment: Didn't work - same thing happening. Refresh shows array, 2 out of 3 times and then does not show array 2 out of 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code and can simply print the array using

```
echo "ARRAY: <pre>" . print_r((array)$return_data_obj, 1) . "</pre>";
```

Comment: I can to 2-3 times and then next time it shows empty array.

Comment: I tried for almost 10 -15 times. It worked all the time.

Comment: What is strange on this as well - issue started happening two days ago, prior to this, this code worked without any problems! I would say its a code that someone else promoted to region, but it can't be when my simplexml method does not return consistently.